# deploy spring boot проекта на сервер

Tags: spring, tomcat

Я делаю дэплой своего проекта на сервер через tomcat mangaer приложение , потом после того как развернул проект в логах получаю ошибку

```
2020-02-06 05:04:42.831 ERROR 6764 --- [io-443-exec-205] o.s.b.w.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter  : Cannot forward to error page for request [/common/fonts/Trebuchet MS.ttf] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false

org.apache.coyote.CloseNowException: Connection [186], Stream [3], This stream is not writable
        at org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2UpgradeHandler.reserveWindowSize(Http2UpgradeHandler.java:843)
        at org.apache.coyote.http2.Stream$StreamOutputBuffer.flush(Stream.java:940)
        at org.apache.coyote.http2.Stream$StreamOutputBuffer.doWrite(Stream.java:859)
        at org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2OutputBuffer.doWrite(Http2OutputBuffer.java:59)
        at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:601)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:339)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flushByteBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:776)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.append(OutputBuffer.java:681)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:386)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:364)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutput
```

Comment: Проблема со шрифтом какая-то

Comment: Как я понимаю, вы в неправильную папку положили шрифт

Comment: Извините , не могли бы уточнить о коком шрифте идет речь ? локально сервер поднял все хорошо работает , а на удаленном сервере выдает ошибку

Comment: так в первой строчке написано - `/common/fonts/Trebuchet MS.ttf`. Возможно, ваш файл находится за пределами проекта (вне папки `resources`)

Comment: Рассмотрите так же [данный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30170586/how-to-disable-errorpagefilter-in-spring-boot/36579956)

Comment: спасибо , однако я пробовал такое не получилось

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте права доступа на чтение и запись к файлу **/common/fonts/Trebuchet MS.ttf** у пользователя под которым на сервере работает ваше приложение (пользователь **tomcat manager**).